# How to write the general formula?

Tags: combinatorics, trees, binary

I have a perfect binary tree that I wish to write the generic formula for. There are $1,2,4,8, ...$ nodes per splitting (as usual). Each node is unique. The equations for the first four rows can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
1&\\
A^{(1)}x +& B^{(1)}y\\
A^{(1)}(A^{(2)}x + B^{(2)}y) +& B^{(1)}(A^{(2)}x+B^{(2)}y)\\
A^{(1)}(A^{(2)}(A^{(3)}x+B^{(3)}y) + B^{(2)}(A^{(3)}x +B^{(3)}y)) +& B^{(1)}(A^{(2)}(A^{(3)}x+B^{(3)}y) + B^{(2)}(A^{(3)}x+B^{(3)}y))\\ 
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
The $x$ and $y$ variables are just place holders to insert the next layer. Each place is now a unique node in the perfect binary tree. Is there a way to write the equation for the $n$th layer?

Comment: I would approach this problem by always taking the equation of the $n$th line and separating the multipliers of $x$ from the multipliers of $y$. You will notice that you will get longer and longer expressions for the coefficients of $x$ and $y$, but there will be a pattern. The first coefficients of $x$ is $A^{(1)}$, the next is $\left(A^{(1)}A^{(2)} + \ldots \right)$, the third is $\left( A^{(1)}A^{(2)} A^{(3)} + \ldots \right)$ etc ...

Comment: The coefficients of $x$ and $y$ will have the forms of something like
$$
\sum_{j \in ???} \prod\limits_{\alpha \in {A, B}} \alpha^{(j)}_i$$

Comment: @MattiP. That is very helpful thank you.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd term coefficients appear to be $$(a_1a_2+a_2b_1)x+(a_1b_2+b_1b_2)y$$
and $$(a_1a_2a_3+a_2a_3b_1+a_1a_3b_2+a_3b_1b_2)x+(a_1a_2b_3+a_2b_1b_3+a_1b_2b_3+b_1b_2b_3)y.$$